# change color hide subsection

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, color

Is it possible to change the color of the hide subsection in the toc. I choose a very dark bg for the slides, this makes it hard to read the hide subsection. I tried to give the hide element a different color.

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]

    {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
    \tableofcontents[
      currentsection,
      sectionstyle=show/hide,
      subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
    ]
    \end{frame}
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `\setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{fg=blue, bg=red}`? Otherwise please add a MWE.

Comment: thy, thats what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour of the shades subsections can be controlled with

```
\setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{fg=blue, bg=red}
```